# Migrating from SQLITE to postgreSQL in django raises " can't adapt type 'CharField'"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, model, migration

I'm using Django 4.1.10 and i'm trying to migrate from sqlite to postgresql but when I try to execute de migration files or dump data from manage.py i get this error

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'CharField'

It happens both whe using python.exe manage.py migrate and  python.exe manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json

Is there any restriction related to datatypes?

Compelte Error code:

```
(venv) PS C:\projects\djangoproject> python.exe .\manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'CharField'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 443, in execute     
    self.check()
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 475, in check       
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks   
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config 
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver   
    return check_method()
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns      
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module    
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\festablas\urls.py", line 27, in <module>
    path('', include('core.urls')),
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\core\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\core\views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .forms import createNewFestival, createNewEdicion, LoginForm, RegisterForm, createNewCompania, createNewObra, uploadImgMontajeForm, uploadImgObraForm, modificarDatosForm, cambiarContraseñaForm
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\core\forms.py", line 101, in <module>
    class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\core\forms.py", line 130, in RegisterForm
    if qs.exists():
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1226, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 592, in has_results  
    return compiler.has_results()
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1366, in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1398, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute        
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute        
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\projects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute        
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'CharField'
```

This is the complete error, i can't manage to find where the origin of the error is.

Comment: Add the complete error message, as text, to your question.  `CharField` is a legitimate Django field type [CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#charfield) and can be used with all backends. There must be something wrong with how this particular is instance is declared.

Comment: I've done it @AdrianKlaver . Thank you

Comment: Hmm, that did not narrow it down. 1) To be clear you are running `.\manage.py dumpdata` against a project that is currently running on SQLite, correct? 2) Have you made any customization's to your models?